# Airflow/Composer UnzipOperator Crashes

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, zip, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I try to run my DAG to process a file of several Gbytes, that is compressed (zip). The dag uses the following operator :

```
    ... # Other operators

    >> UnzipOperator(task_id="unzip_archive",
    path_to_zip_file=archive_path,
    path_to_unzip_contents=unzipped_f_path)

    ... # Other operators
```

It seems the DAG crashes, with this log :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2020-06-26 15:10:56,157] {models.py:1599} INFO - Executing <Task(UnzipOperator): unzip_archive> on 2020-06-26T14:34:15+00:00
[2020-06-26 15:10:56,163] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run fota_integration.fota_user_profile unzip_archive 2020-06-26T14:34:15+00:00 --job_id 227634 --pool integration --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/fota/fota_integration.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmpdht77jvb']
[2020-06-26 15:11:12,208] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:12,207] {settings.py:176} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800, pid=297
[2020-06-26 15:11:21,582] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:21,537] {default_celery.py:90} WARNING - You have configured a result_backend of redis://airflow-redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local:6379/0, it is highly recommended to use an alternative result_backend (i.e. a database).
[2020-06-26 15:11:21,692] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:21,692] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2020-06-26 15:11:28,126] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:28,022] {app.py:52} WARNING - Using default Composer Environment Variables. Overrides have not been applied.
[2020-06-26 15:11:28,650] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:28,617] {configuration.py:522} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2020-06-26 15:11:29,279] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:29,270] {configuration.py:522} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2020-06-26 15:11:31,908] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:31,900] {models.py:273} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/gcs/dags/fota/fota_integration.py
[2020-06-26 15:11:35,673] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:35,670] {cli.py:520} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: fota_integration.fota_user_profile.unzip_archive 2020-06-26T14:34:15+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-778c879665-zgjbn
[2020-06-26 15:11:36,086] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:36,080] {zip.py:136} INFO - Executing UnzipOperator.execute(context)
[2020-06-26 15:11:36,086] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:36,084] {zip.py:138} INFO - path_to_zip_file: /home/airflow/gcs/data/zips/20200626_USER_PROFILE.zip
[2020-06-26 15:11:36,086] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:36,084] {zip.py:140} INFO - path_to_unzip_contents: /home/airflow/gcs/data/raw_data/20200626/USER_PROFILE/
[2020-06-26 15:11:36,365] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:36,365] {zip.py:155} INFO - Created zip file object '<zipfile.ZipFile filename='/home/airflow/gcs/data/zips/20200626_USER_PROFILE.zip' mode='r'>' from path '/home/airflow/gcs/data/zips/20200626_USER_PROFILE.zip'
[2020-06-26 15:11:36,365] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:11:36,365] {zip.py:158} INFO - Extracting all the contents to '/home/airflow/gcs/data/raw_data/20200626/USER_PROFILE/'
[2020-06-26 15:43:25,451] {helpers.py:250} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 297
[2020-06-26 15:43:25,529] {models.py:1641} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2020-06-26 15:43:25,533] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:43:25,529] {models.py:1641} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2020-06-26 15:43:29,047] {helpers.py:250} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 297
[2020-06-26 15:43:29,048] {models.py:1641} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2020-06-26 15:43:29,054] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 227634: Subtask unzip_archive [2020-06-26 15:43:29,048] {models.py:1641} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2020-06-26 15:43:38,943] {helpers.py:232} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=297, status='terminated') (297) terminated with exit code 0
```

Then when I try to re-run, I get this log :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 2 of 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2020-07-01 09:14:33,615] {models.py:1599} INFO - Executing <Task(UnzipOperator): unzip_archive> on 2020-06-26T14:34:15+00:00
[2020-07-01 09:14:33,616] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run fota_integration.fota_user_profile unzip_archive 2020-06-26T14:34:15+00:00 --job_id 231875 --pool integration --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/fota/fota_integration.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmp0uwqdre9']
```

I want to say that obviously, insufficient memory triggers a SIGKILL... But When I check the code of the `UnzipOperator` library, I find the payload is not imported into memory.

Here's the unzip operator's main loop.

```
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
         open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
        shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

It is located in `_extract_member(self, member, targetpath, pwd)`, which is used in `extractall(self, path=None, members=None, pwd=None)`, which is used in `execute(self, context)` of the `UnzipOperator` class.

My questions :

1. Why does the SIGKILL happen?
2. How do I fix this?

EDIT :

I linked another question to this problem, as I am not sure of the validity of the analysis within it. It is linked with the inability to write a python file without loading it entirely into memory. [Find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62681614/how-do-i-write-a-file-in-python-without-loading-it-into-memory).

Comment: `SIGTERM` is usually the result of the job heartbeat failing, which can be an indirect symptom of overload. Can you post the Airflow worker's logs during that time?

Comment: @hexacyanide, not sure how to do that. I'm using composer (kubernetes cluster)

Comment: To help isolate the cause of the SIGTERM, you can install strace in one of the worker containers and then try to track the PID/name of the process which is causing the SIGTERM. Here's how you can do it https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox#installing_and_running_tools_from_toolbox

Comment: To further troubleshoot this, you can report it on https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 1):

That's an unfortunate case. Where the error from the inflation isn't being brought up through the Python Exception chain.

Can you get onto the instance to unzip the object directly? Hopefully, that will yield enough error data for you to act on. Alternatively, give you the possibility of using something like the BashOperator if you can't find the issue.

---

I might know what's happened [2020-06-26 15:11:36,365] --- [2020-06-26 15:43:25,451]... that's 30 mins... is that expected?.... my guess is the unzip operator is simply not yielding enough data to the executor or the scheduler that maybe the scheduler itself thinks the job is done or out of time... some time out logic is hit and the process shuts down.

There are ways to update or extend this timeout. Hopefully that's enough to help

Comment: Indeed, a bash operator could do the trick... Except it bugs me not to know where it fails exactly. I need to understand

Comment: I'm not sure it's the timeout, as the file is 5 Gb, plus a simple re-run would've yielded at least the same response, but the second run was empty... Signifying an abrupt interruption of the process